# Emulation performace : x86 vs ARM

Tags: performance, arm, x86, emulation

Some time ago I ran an `ARM` android image inside the android `AVD` in my `x86` system and it was too slow to even move the cursor smoothly. Since it needs to actually translate `ARM` instructions to `x86` on the fly.

So the question is "Is ARM harder to emulate or is x86?"

I mean given two CPUs , one x86 and one ARM with almost same performance in different areas ( just an assumption ), which one is ***inherently*** faster? ARM emulation on x86 or x86 emulation on ARM?

I think since x86 instruction are very complex, it requires a lot of work to compile it just-in-time ( but not vice versa ). Am I correct? or is it possible at all to come to a reasonable conclusion?

Comment: it could be that the ARM instruction set is more efficient, and requires multiple x86 instructions to emulate one ARM instruction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least some x86 processors have a RISC processor inside, emulating the x86.

Where as no one in their right mind would use an x86 to emulate a RISC processor. Unless they have to (see your use case).

Having lots of registers helps (ARM has lots of registers).

Also emulating a small instruction set using a large instruction set is a waste. The large instruction set will slow it down, with no benefit.